# How to prove a tempered distribution always has a order?

Tags: distribution-theory

I just learn some  distribution theory.

In Friedlander's book, "Introduction to the theory of distributions" (page 97),  he said:   The dual of $\mathscr{S}(R^n)$ (Schwartz Space) consists of continuous linear forms on $\mathscr{S}(R^n)$; Obviously, such a linear form $u$ is continuous if and only if there is a constant $C\geq 0$ and a nonnegative integer N such that 
\begin{equation}
   |<u,\phi>|\leq C \sum_{|\alpha|,|\beta|\leq N}  \sup |x^\alpha\partial^\beta \phi| \quad, \forall \phi\in \mathscr{S}(R^n)
\end{equation}

This means that all tempered distribution always have a order (right?). I can't prove that "obviously " fact. Can anyone help me or give a hint?

By the way:  $\mathscr{S}(R^n)$ means Schwartz space. Here is the wiki link, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space

And linear form is "continuous" means  it a linear  & it is continuous in the topological sense.

Answer (score 5):

It's the standard "continuous implies bounded" argument: Let
\begin{equation}
   \Vert\phi\Vert_N:= \sum_{|\alpha|,|\beta|\leq N}  \sup |x^\alpha\partial^\beta \phi|. 
\end{equation}
If your inequality fails then for every $N$ then there is a $0\neq\phi_N\in\mathscr S$ s.t.
$$|\langle u,\phi_N\rangle|\geq N\Vert\phi_N\Vert_N.$$
Let $\psi_N=\phi_N/(N \Vert\phi_N\Vert_N)$. Then $\psi_N\to 0$ in $\mathscr S$, but $|\langle u,\psi_N\rangle|\geq 1$, so $\langle u,\psi_N\rangle$ doesn't converge to $0$.

Comment: I think you are right.   Thanks.